# Get (max) N rows of a DataFrame at a time

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame() #A dataframe with 99 rows

df.shape[0]
#99
```

and I want to iterate over that, getting 10 rows at a time. That can be done e.g by using `range(0,99,10)` and loop over that. The issue is that the last 9 elements will be ignored - to overcome this, we can make it run uptil 90, and take the rest.
I would like to avoid creating such a loop manually, thus I wonder if there is a better way to iterate over the dataframe (or any iterable element actually), such that I get (max) `N=10` elements at a time thus in the end, the last slize contains 9 elements?

Answer (score 2):

given an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,99*3).reshape(99,3))
```

output:

```
    0   1   2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9   10  11
4   12  13  14
... ... ... ...
94  282 283 284
95  285 286 287
96  288 289 290
97  291 292 293
98  294 295 296
```

you can split it by groups-> first set a column to group items:

```
df['groups'] =  df.index // 10 #  <<< thanks to henry for the suggestion
df
```

output:

```
    0   1   2   groups
0   0   1   2   0.0
1   3   4   5   0.0
2   6   7   8   0.0
3   9   10  11  0.0
4   12  13  14  0.0
... ... ... ... ...
94  282 283 284 90.0
95  285 286 287 90.0
96  288 289 290 90.0
97  291 292 293 90.0
98  294 295 296 90.0
```

second, split it with `groupby`:

```
for index, group_df in df.groupby('groups'):
     print(index) # this is the number eg: 0,10,20...
     print(group_df) # this is the dataframe from index to index +10 / last item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the dataframe like:

```
for i in range(0,99,10):
    batch = df.iloc[i:10+i,]
```